# Jess - % equivalent operation

Tags: jess

I am starting to learn Jess and I want to know if there is in Jess an equivalent operation to the % in Java? By the way, there is something in the internet that you recommend to learn it?

For example:

```
(bind ?z (Symbol 5 7))

?z = 5

(bind ?z (Symbol 49 7))

?z = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jess function you want is

```
(mod <numeric-expression> <numeric-expression>)
```

As for learning Jess, there Earnest Friedman-Hill's book (not on the internet, AFAIK) is still the best, I hear. But the manual that comes with Jess is very good, and you can learn a lot from that.

Since Jess is a Lisp dialect, you can learn from any tutorial on Lisp. Then, browse the reference, just to get an idea what is available.